# Ask user to input user name when running a powershell or command line

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to create a command to add a domain user to the local administrator group. I already have the command to do it:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member domain\user
```

or

```
net localgroup Administrators Domain\user /add
```

But I need to ask the user to insert him credentials when run the script. How do I do this?

Comment: The user would need to be already member of that group to be able to add someone (itself) to the group. The current user would be `$ENV:UserName`. ;-)

Comment: The user will receive a machine and a local user account (admin), them will login to the machine and run the script to add him domain account to Local Machine administrator group

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Credential` is what you want:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

This will prompt the user to enter their username and password in a secure fashion. However...

You can't add a user to a group you aren't a member of, or at least have permissions delegated to manage members of that group (such as local Administrators). If the running user could do this already, entering their credentials wouldn't be required.

If the running user were already in `Administrators`, you would not need this either, just provide the target principal name (since adding yourself to the Administrators group requires that you already be in `Administrators`) and make sure your session is elevated.

---

Honestly, just use a Restricted Groups GPO to control domain users and their local group status. You don't want local users able to manage their local admin group in most situations anyways. If someone *does* change the membership, the change will gracefully revert on the next `gpupdate` interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
```

It will give you windows login window.

Also there is a way to extract that data like this:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Credentials.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content C:\test\password.txt
$Username = $Credentials.Username
$Password = Get-Content “C:\test\password.txt” | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username,$Password
```

There is more in here:

https://sysadminguides.org/2017/05/02/how-to-pass-credentials-in-powershell/

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Good info on `Get-Credential` but unfortunately this will not solve OP's problem. They are asking how to get the credential but they want to use it to have a user add themselves to a group (`Administrators` in this case). They will be able to enter the credential but they cannot use it to self-add themselves to a group.

Comment: I see. But look, I believe that I'm not being clear. Let me explain it better. 
I'll send 50 new machines setup in the domain to an remote office, there is no owner for those machines. So I'll create local administrator account to future new hires. When a machine need to be used, I'll provide the local administrator account that was created, so the new hire will connect to Internet and VPN (to have connection to domain) them he will run the script to add him DOMAIN Account to Administrator group. User is logged with a local admin account just for 1st login and after need to login using the...

Comment: Using him corporate account that was provided by the manager or HR. I'm trying to save that time explaining to each user on how to open lusrmgr.msc and include the corporate account into local admin. My idea is tell the employee (that will be logged with a random local admin account) run the script to include him domain account into admin group. But I need this tip to ask user to insert the username because I'll let those machines with the script...Is it clear now? Thanks anyway guys.